# What does execvp actually do?

Tags: c, shell, exec, execvp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a shell - how to execute commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473751/writing-a-shell-how-to-execute-commands)

I've been tasked with writing a shell in C. So far I understand that execvp will try to run the program in arg1 with arg2 as parameters. Now it seems that doing this

```
execvp ("ls", args); //assume args is {"ls", ">", "awd.txt"}
```

is not equivalent to typing this in the console

```
ls > awd.txt
```

I realize that I need to use freopen to achieve the same results but I'm curious what execvp is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec` family of functions are ultimately a system call. System calls go straight into the kernel and typically perform a very specific service that only the kernel can do.

Redirection, on the other hand, is a shell feature.

So, when one types `ls > awd.txt` at a shell, the shell first does a `fork(2)`, then it closes standard output in the child, then it opens `awd.txt` on file descriptor one so that it's the new standard output.

Then, and only then, the shell will make an `exec-`family system call.

In your case you simply passed the strings `>` and `awd.txt` to the exec system call, and from there to `ls`. BTW, be sure you terminate your execvp arg array with a null pointer.

---

<sup>Note: As you can see, the redirection operators are never seen by the executed program. Before Unix, directing output to a file had to be done by every program based on an option. More trivia: most programs never know they were redirected, but ironically, `ls` *does* check to see if its output is a tty, and if so, it does the multi-column formatted output thing.</sup>

Comment: Absolutely. As a shell writer, redirection and pipelining is your job. 'ls' doesn't know to do anything with '>' other than try to open it for listing, so you'll be told that it can't access '>'. Also don't forget to terminate your args with a NULL pointer so it knows to stop.

Answer (score 0):

It's executing `ls` with 2 arguments: `>` and `awd.txt`. It is equivalent to running:

```
'ls' '>' 'awd.txt'
```

Comment: So to execute ls -a in execvp(), we should do execvp ("ls", args); //args is {"ls", "-a"}? or, execvp (args[0], args)?Nice simple explanation though!

Comment: @SittingBull: As noted in a comment to your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447544/), you'd need `char *args[] = { "ls", "-a", 0 };` where the terminating null pointer is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your command directly to the shell:

```
char * const args[] = { "sh", "-c", "ls > awd.txt", NULL};
execvp("/bin/sh", args);
```

But it doesn't seems like a good idea.