# Trying to understand how execvp works

Tags: c, unix, execvp

I found so many explanations and answers on `execvp` but it all seems confusing. `execvp` takes a command and sends it to kernel and then does something, `execvp` creates an image, `execvp` is system call, `execvp` ...etc. As a beginner with limited C language and Linux experience, only the following [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544519/) seemed to click for me:

> It's executing `ls` with 2 arguments: `>` and `awd.txt`. It is equivalent to running:
>
> ```
> 'ls' '>' 'awd.txt'
> ```

Here is the thread: [What does execvp actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544501/what-does-execvp-actually-do)

However, I asked the following question to the person who answered and he did not reply, hence I'm asking separately in a desperate attempt to understand it.

So to execute `ls -a` in `execvp`, we should do `execvp ("ls", args)`; where `args` is `{"ls", "-a"}`? or `execvp (args[0], args)`?

Can someone tell me if it's true: `execvp` takes the first argument from the array `args` and then sends that to kernel to follow the following array arguments? So `execvp(args[0],args);` would be that from `args [] = {"ls", "-a"}` array the `args[0]` takes `ls`, sends it to the kernel and then what?It goes looking for another `args[0]` and finds `-a` and sends that, and the kernel determines that these two makes a command like `ls -a`?

Comment: To execute `ls -a`, you'd need: `char *args[] = { "ls", "-a", 0 };` where the trailing null pointer (written `0` — could be `NULL` if you prefer) is crucial. It marks the end of the argument list, just like in `argv` in the `main()` program. Assuming the name given is simple (no slashes), what it does is look up directories named on the `PATH` environment variable and concatenates the directory with the executable name and tries `execv(pathname, args)`. If it succeeds, it doesn't get another chance; if it fails, it tries the next directory on `PATH` until it succeeds or there's nothing left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype is:

```
  int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

The first argument, `file` is the name of the program to execute. `execvp` will search your path and try to find a match. From the manpage:

> The  execlp(),  execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the
>    actions of the shell in searching for an executable file if the
>    specified file name does not contain a slash (/) character.
>    The file is sought in the colon-separated list of directory
>    pathnames specified in the PATH environment  variable.

If/when execvp finds a match, that program will be loaded into memory and replace your current running program.

The arguments the new program will see are the `argv` array specified in execvp. You are expected to have a null pointer as the last element, or your program may crash looking for a null.

If you do:

```
char *argv[]={"bar","bash","penguin",0};
execvp("foo",argv);
```

then when foo starts, it will have the same environment as your current program, its argc will be 3 and its argv will be the above list. Even though the program name is "foo", it's argv[0] while running will show up as "bar".

You don't actually have to have argv[0] be the name of the new program. It is expected, but not required.

Incidentally, with your example of

```
ls > awd.txt
```

If you did this on the command line, your shell would fork creating a new copy of itself. The child shell would open awd.txt and do a dup2() to put the child fd attached to awd.txt as 1. After some other housekeeping, the child shell would do something like.

```
execvp("ls", {"ls", 0})
```

so in the created "ls" argc==1 and argv[1] ==0.  Traditionally , we would say that ls has 0 arguments.